Counting sets of values in a column associated with another columns values
I am asking for a solution to this scenario in Excel.
I want to get a count of sets of unique values in one column that are associated to values in another column.
Example:
A  B  C
1  a  3
1  a  3
2  a  3
2  a  3
3  a  3
4  b  1
In column A there are 4 unique values in the data set. Duplicates that extend from data links are unavoidable in this scenario. I would like a formula in Excel that will show the number of sets associated with the values in column B. The results would match the data in column C where the formulas would be placed. 3 different sets are associated with value "a" in column B. And 1 set is associated with value "b" in column b.
I was trying to utilize a formula of =COUNTIFS() but I was having trouble separating the unique sets that were connected to the unique values in column B. I am not sure if a dummy column would help for a combination of formulas. Any help or suggestions would be appreciated! this data set is being scrapped into Excel for analysis. Pulling out column A to pick remove duplicates is not ideal. Occurrences must be in column C for transfer to Tableau visual tool mapping.

You can use FILTER and UNIQUE.
I assume your data is in range A1:B6, you can use below formula and drag down:
=COUNT(UNIQUE(FILTER($A$1:$A$6,$B$1:$B$6=B1,""),FALSE,FALSE))


You are a genius. Sadly the Excel version I am using at the location doing this does not have the “Unique” function like I do on my personal. Unless there is also a way to get it as an add in.

@Elijah for older version you could try: =SUMPRODUCT(IF($B$1:$B$6=B1,1/COUNTIFS($B$1:$B$6,B1,$A$1:$A$6,$A$1:$A$6),0)) also before posting any query, should research the forum, all these questions have been multiple times resolved

The difficulty is finding the right key word to search...

If you dont try to research the forum, you will never get.

Thank you for the advice. Unfortunately the formula you provided did not have the same affect as the first answer given. Unfortunately the Excel I’m currently workin from is the 2019 version.

@Elijah fortunately i use Excel and have made ample of tests to mark is as duplicate. Also the solutions posted are based on Excel 2019 version!

A Count of Distinct Values Per Group
=LET(data,A2:B7,g_col,2,u_col,1,
    u,CHOOSECOLS(data,u_col),
    g,CHOOSECOLS(data,g_col),
    gu,UNIQUE(g),
    uc,BYROW(gu,LAMBDA(r,ROWS(UNIQUE(FILTER(u,g=r))))),
    XLOOKUP(g,gu,uc))


